# django admin list filter queryset dependent on change list results

Tags: django, django-admin, django-filters

This is for Django 1.8

**models.py**

```
class ProductClass(models.Model):
    product_class = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.secondary_class  


class Product(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    product_class = models.ForeignKey(ProductClass, db_index=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to display a list filter  in the ProductAdmin with a list if Product Classifications with the number of products next to each entry.

**by  Product Class**

- Books (100)
- Pens (10)
- Rulers (33)

I've managed to do this for the super set of data

**admin.py**

```
class DynamicProductClassFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('Product Class')    

    # Parameter for the filter that will be used in the URL query.
    parameter_name = 'p_class'         

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        classes = ProductClass.objects.annotate(number_products=Count('product'))

        return [(c.id, '%s (%s)' % (c.product_class , c.number_products)) for c in classes]
```

Now I want to have this updated based on other filters that are applied to the dataset, whether that's search criteria or other list filters being applied.

I thought I could use the fact that 'request' and 'model_admin' are available in the 'def queryset' of a list filter. after many different attempts I ended up with the following code

```
def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    products = model_admin.get_queryset(request)
    product_ids = products.values_list('id', flat=True)
    classes = ProductClass.objects.filter(product__id__in=product_ids).annotate(number_products=Count('product'))

    return [(c.id, '%s (%s)' % (c.product_class, c.number_products)) for c in classes]
```

But unfortunately this is not getting the filters being applied to the main dataset.

I'm very new to django and python so I apologise if there is basic knowledge missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that works for me now but I would still like feedback/advice on how this can be done better and in a more generic/maintainable way.

```
def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    concept_filter = request.GET.get('p_concept', None)
    if concept_filter:
        classes = ProductClass.objects.filter(product__title__concept_id=concept_filter).annotate(number_products=Count('product'))
    else:
        classes = ProductClass.objects.annotate(number_products=Count('product'))

    return [(c.id, '%s (%s)' % (c.product_class, c.number_products)) for c in classes]
```

I found that I could get the filter criteria being applied to the changelist dataset by using

```
concept_filter = request.GET.get('p_concept', None)
```

Which for my use case works just fine as I would prefer to have this list filter only dependent on the one other filter.

It would be interesting to know how to modify this solution so you could loop through all query parameters and know how to construct the query correctly. I don't know where you would get the association between a parameter name and the column it needs to filter against though. Maybe just naming conventions would help here.